# IDE for writing and running hadoop jobs?

Tags: java, hadoop, ide

I have recently started learning the basics of Hadoop map-reduce programming in Java. So far, the only way I found is writing the code in a file using vi or emacs which seems awful, primitive and very painful.

Is there any IDE for writing, compiling and running Hadoop programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also check out the IntelliJ IDEA as the Apache Hadoop wiki pages have instructions on how to set up your development environment using it.

References:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopUnderIDEA

Answer (score 4):

Use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). Cloudera has a great screencast [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/04/configuring-eclipse-for-hadoop-development-a-screencast/) for configuring eclipse for hadoop development.
Also debugging a hadoop job locally is pretty cool using eclipse (though not trivial). To know more on that, see [here](http://amnigos.com/post/44631353593/how-to-guide-hadoop-mapreduce-debugging-in-lo).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/10/debugging-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in.html) is a blog for Debugging/Developing Hadoop Jobs on Eclipse/Linux. Also, check [Karmasphere Studio](http://karmasphere.com/karmasphere-studio-resources).

Comment: Thanks for the blog link. It was helpful. But is it possible to link my eclipse to a hadoop cluster and run jobs on them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible to run the MapReduce jobs in Eclipse. There is a lot of difference running MapReduce programs on a cluster and in Eclipse.
Bellow are the few points worth noting:

- In Eclipse, it runs in a special mode called: LocalJobRunner mode i.e. all Hadoop daemons are run in single JVM.
- In Eclipse, All paths refer to local file paths, and not to HDFS path.